# Forced mate: 2 queens vs king

Tags: checkmate, problems, queens

On the board, there are 2 queens (of the same color) placed on random squares. The opposing side has only a king, placed on a random square (and not in check). There obviously exists a mating sequence. What is the biggest possible 'n' such that there is a forced Mate in 'n'? In other words, given the above situation, what is the upper bound on the minimum number of moves required to give a checkmate?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question but I have a comment that may be relevant to your research. This link has mate in 2 puzzles with two queens vs a lone king: https://www.apronus.com/chess/puzzles/mate-in-2/?KQQvK

Comment: "There obviously exists a mating sequence." Except for stalemates.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire The solution to that is not to stalemate.

Comment: @You'rebadandshouldfeelbad I think the stalemate comment was intended to point out the possibility that the "random" starting position in the question might be stalemate.

Answer (score 14):

The longest KQQ-K mate whilst maintaining optimality is a [mate in 4](http://www.gilith.com/chess/endgames/kqq_k.html).

```
[FEN "8/8/8/3k4/8/5K2/8/4Q2Q w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Wouldn't 1... Kd4 give one more movement to the black?

Comment: @fedorqui, in that case, 2. Qc7 (Kd5 3. Qe4#) (Kd3 3. Qe3#) mate in 3.

Comment: Yes, this seems right. I played a lot in an analysis board and couldn't find a position which requires mate in 5.